# How to get all words with the same prefix in a list? C#

Tags: c#, list, autocomplete, prefix

I am working on a college project and I am stumped on how to get all the words with the prefix ("he") printed using Console.WriteLine. Here is my code so far, as you can see I already tried but it is highlighting my GetWordsForPrefix("he") in red. Thank you! (dont mind the other stuff, it is other scenarios I have to implement)

` static void Main(string[] args)
{
List words = new List();

```
        words.Add("car");
        words.Add("caramael");
        words.Add("hey");
        words.Add("hello");
        words.Add("helloeverybody");
        words.Add("CSC204");


        // Console.WriteLine("Scenario 1:");
        // Console.WriteLine();
        // foreach (string word in words)
        // {
        //      Console.WriteLine(word);
        //  }

        foreach (string word in words.GetWordsForPrefix("he"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nScenario 5 Printing all words:");
        words.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Scenario 6 Insert  \"car\":");
        int index = words.BinarySearch("car");
        if (index < 0)
        {
            words.Insert(~index, "car");
        }
        

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error, This word already exsits");
        }

    }


}`
```

Comment: Where do you define `GetWordsForPrefix`?

Comment: You might want `words.Where(w => w.StartsWith("he"))` instead

Comment: You are not getting an error on the line... `List words = new List();` .... this is invalid and should probably be.... `List<string> words = new List<string>();` .... then you need to write/implement the `GetWordsForPrefix` method.

Answer (score 1):

If words is a List, then use LINQ Where().

## Make List of Words

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.Add("car");
words.Add("caramael");
words.Add("hey");
words.Add("hello");
words.Add("helloeverybody");
words.Add("CSC204");
```

## Query list of words

```
var results = words.Where( (x) => x.StartsWith("he"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you are required to implement a method called `GetWordsForPrefix`. This method is obviously not a method in a `List`’s properties.

Also, as I commented, I am confident you would get an error on the line…

```
List words = new List();
```

A `List` needs a “type” of something. In this case I will assume you need a `string` type…

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
```

Then to get all the words in the list that start with “he” could go something like…

```
foreach (string word in words) {
  if (word.StartsWith("he")) {
    Console.WriteLine(word);
  }
}
```

If you are required to implement a `GetWordsForPrefix` method, then that method would need a list of all words and a string “prefix.” Then the method would return a list of all the words that start with the given prefix. Something like…

```
private static List<string> GetWordsForPrefix(List<string> allWords, string prefix) {
  List<string> prefixWords = new List<string>();
  foreach (string word in allWords) {
    if (word.StartsWith(prefix)) {
      prefixWords.Add(word);
    }
  }
  return prefixWords;
}
```

Then you could call this method in a similar way as your current code. Something like…

```
foreach (string word in GetWordsForPrefix(words, "he")) {
  Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot! Everything worked well for me!